# Processing vector objects in java

Tags: java, vector

i have a vector of objects, which needs to processed by using start and end index.If end index is same for multilpe objects, i have to keep only bigger string in `name`.And have to the same with start index, like below

```
vector =start:21 end:24 name:abc
         start:22 end:24 name:bc
         start:28 end:31 name:xyz
         start:29 end:31 name:yz
         start:30 end:31 name:z
         start:45 end:51 name:robert
         start:45 end:48 name:rob
```

I have to process this vector and print in the following way.

```
vector =start:21 end:24 name:abc
         start:28 end:31 name:xyz
         start:45 end:51 name:robert
```

I have tried something like below

```
    for(int i=0;i<vecotr.size();i++)
        {
            NameBuffer b=vecotr.get(i);
            if(i+1<vecotr.size())
            {

            NameBuffer b1=vecotr.get(i+1);

            if(b.end==b1.end )
            {
                if(b.name.length()>b1.name.length())
                {
                    vector.remove(i+1);

                }   
            }
            if(b.begin==b1.begin )
            {
                if(b.name.length()>b1.name.length())
                {
                    vector.remove(i+1);

                }

            }

            }

            }
```

NameBuffer constructor:

```
public NameBuffer(String oneLine) {
    try {
        String[] parts = oneLine.split("\\s*\\|\\s*");
        String tmp = parts[0].substring("start:".length());
        this.begin = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
        String tmp1 = parts[1].substring("end:".length());
        this.end = Integer.parseInt(tmp1);
        String tmp2 = parts[3].substring("name:".length());
        this.name = tmp2;

    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.print("XML is not in a desired Format");
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public String toString()

  ----------------
  ----------------
```

The above code sample is not deleting all the entries with same end index or start index.It was able to delete `name:bc` and `name:yz` but not `name:z`

Answer (score 0):

After `vector.remove(i+1);` add `i--;`.

Then, after removing an element, it will check that element again in case it matches more than one of the elements after it.

Comment: that makes the loop infinite

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the following sequence part:

```
[2]: start:28 end:31 name:xyz
[3]: start:29 end:31 name:yz
[4]: start:30 end:31 name:z
```

Now if `i == 2` you're checking `i + 1 == 3` as well and remove the element at index 3.
Next, i  is set to 3 which now compares the element at index 3 (`z`) with the element at index 4 (`robert`) and since neither start nor end are matching, you're not removing.

You might try and solve this by moving backwards, i.e. from `i = vector.size() - 2` to `i = 0`, compare the elements at `i` and `i + 1` (which always should be present due to starting at the next to last element).

That way you'd compare elements 3 and 4 and would keep 3 (`yz`). Then i is set to 2 and you now compare elements 2 and 3, keeping element 2 afterwards (`xyz`).

If the biggest element was at the end of a sequence that wouldn't matter.
Consider this:

```
[0]: a
[1]: ab
[2]: abc
```

You'd first compare `ab` and `abc` with i being 1. Then you remove `ab` which makes `abc` move to index 1. In the next iteration i is decremented to 0 and you now compare `a` and `abc`, removing `a` this time.

Btw, your code might remove too much, if two elements had the same start and end index. Thus check all conditions first and if any of those matches remove only once.

Here's an adapted version of your loop:

```
for(int i = vector.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--)
{
   // no need to check here, the loop ensures that i  and i+1 are within the bounds
   NameBuffer b=vector.get(i);
   NameBuffer b1=vector.get(i+1);

   if(b.end==b1.end || b.begin==b1.begin)
   {
     if(b.name.length()>b1.name.length())
     {
       vector.remove(i+1);
     }   
     else
     {
       vector.remove(i);
     }
   }
}
```

Another note: consider using `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`.

*An important note*: this would require your vector/list to be sorted by start and end index, so make sure you're doing that first.